# Como hacer que python reste correctamente números decimales

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy trabajando en una aplicación de práctica que tiene una calculadora de operaciones básicas integrada en ella; no tengo mucho conocimiento del lenguaje ya que eh dejado de programar un par de meses.
Bueno, el problema es que al momento de restar 12.05 con 12.03 me da como resultado 0.02000000000000135 y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que solo salga 0.02 sin escribir mucho código[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias!!!!! x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las formas más sencillas que puedes hacer para obtener lo que quieres es la siguiente rutina (que puedes modificar para que coincida con tu codigo), automáticamente se ajusta a tus necesidades de resolución y además sin importar nada!:

```
#los número a restar
a = 12.05
b = 12.032

#se determina la cantidad de decimales que tienen cada número
nda = len(str(a)[str(a).find("."):])-1
ndb = len(str(b)[str(b).find("."):])-1

# se determina la maxima presicion requerida
ndm = max(nda, ndb)

#se crea al codificador de resolución
mcf = "%." + str(ndm) +"f"

#la operación requerida
c = a - b

#se imprime el resultado
print( mcf %  c)
```

Y listo!, ya tienes tu operación con la resolución requerida. En principio esto debería funcionar para la mayoría de las operaciones con numeros lejos de los problemas que pueden generar la resolución de float con decimales.

Comment: es cierto que soluciona ese problema de manera mas sencilla pero me gustaría saber mas a detalle lo que hiciste con el """ .find(".") y el max(nda,nbd) """

Comment: mi variable nda (número de decimales de a) justamente verifica cuantos decimales tiene el número a. Como lo hago, primero convierto el número en string ( str(a) ) de manera que puedo buscar donde se encuentra el punto decimal ( find(".") , este comando me devuelve el índice donde se encuentra el "."). Para terminar determino cuantos decimales hay viendo el tamaño ( len() ) de lo que queda DESPUÉS del punto decimal (por eso están los corchetes y el ":" ). El -1 es por que  no debemos contar el punto como un decimal.

Comment: Esta misma parte se repite para los decimales de b. Por último me debo quedar con la máxima resolución que se haya introducido, por eso utilizo el max (nda, ndb) para saber cual fue el número con mayor número de decimales, de esa manera sé cuantos debo desplegar en el resultado (mcf)

Comment: ohh!!!, mas claro ahora, pero solo tengo una ultima duda amigo, en " '%. + str(ndm) + f " ¿Que función hace el "%." y el " f "  y porque al momento de imprimir también pones un "%"? , Muchísimas gracias de antemano x)

Comment: Esa ultima instrucción es la que hace la configuración de la impresión de salida de un numero float. El comando es %.nf donde "n" es el número de decimales que quieres. De esta manera cuando creo la variable mcf al número de decimales lo "encierro" entre %. y f, de manera que se configura.

Comment: Ohhh vaya todo mas claro ahora gracias amigo me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de punto flotante. To understand it, think about 2/3 = 0.666666667. La respuesta real es 0.666 recurrente. Pero lo redondeamos a 0.6667 con un cierto nivel de precisión.

Debido a que los puntos flotantes son una representación binaria, terminamos con el mismo error que ocurre al agregar 0.05 y 0.03. Si desea controlar la precisión para que se muestre de una manera que coincida con nuestro sistema de números decimales, use el paquete decimal. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Lo siento por mi español (traductor de google).

Answer (score 1):

Los números no enteros se representan en el ordenador de forma aproximada. Para representarlos de forma exacta, se necesitarían infinitos decimales. Esto es debido a que se usa base 2 como sistema de representación.

En base 10 (la que solemos utilizar) a veces aparecen números con infinitos decimales (periódicos), como por ejemplo al dividir 1/3, que sale 0.333... la secuencia de 3 no termina nunca.

En base 2 este problema aparece mucho más a menudo. Números que en base 10 tendrían un solo decimal como 0.2, al pasarlos a base 2 presentan una secuencia infinita de decimales (sería 0.0011001100110011....). De hecho, los únicos números que tienen representación "exacta" en base 2 son los que son suma de potencias de 0.5, como 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.75, etc. (todos terminan en 5).

Esto es un problema en el software bancario, ya que típicamente se trabaja con céntimos que, al convertirse a binario, dan una representación infinita. El ordenador no puede obviamente guardar infinitos bits, así que "corta" la secuencia para dejarla finita, provocando un error de redondeo. El error suele ser pequeño, pero muchos errores sumados puede provocar el descuadre de cuentas en el banco.

Para este tipo de software en python puedes usar el módulo `decimal`, que representa las cantidades con céntimos de otra forma que no produzca esos errores. A cambio la representación es más ineficiente y los cálculos más lentos.

Si no te importa tanto el valor almacenado en la variable (que puede contener un error de redondeo) como su representación por pantalla, es decir, si lo que quieres es que muestre 0.02 aunque internamente esté almacenando un número binario que no es exactamente 0.02, sino 0.02000000000000135, entonces basta que indiques a la hora de imprimirlo que redondee. Esto puedes hacerlo así:

```
print("El resultado es {:f}".format(resultadio))
```

Por defecto te lo muestra redondeado a 6 decimeles, pero puedes controlar la cantidad de decimales que quieres mostrar, por ejemplo, dos decimales:

```
print("El resultado es {:.2f}".format(resultadio))
```

Si quieres que Python redondee automáticamente a la cantidad apropiada de decimales, según el número a mostrar, puedes usar:

```
print("El resultado es {:g}".format(resultadio))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos lo que me respondieron.

Bueno digamos que encontre una solucion y es usando el modulo decimal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me gustaria que alguien me dijera si esta bien hacerlo de esa forma o si hay otra manera mas corta y sencilla....Gracias x)